# jQuery click behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a menu. This menu, will change the background image when you click on a link, as almost all menus do. If I click in one link from the menu, this link background will change the color.

My [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) script is:

```
$(function() { 
 $('#menu ul li').click(function() {
  $('#menu ul li').removeClass("current_page_item");
  $(this).addClass("current_page_item");
  //return false;
 });
});
```

Today, with the "return false" commented, when I click on the link under "#menu ul li" it changes the background open the new page and the background is reset. For sure, if I uncomment the `return false`, the background works fine but then I cannot open any links. So it looks like after that I open a new page, it resets the classes. How can I make it persistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically added classes won't persist between page loads. Consider using some server side code to add the class `current_page_item` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do this *after* the page loads rather than before. You could do it server side as Jud suggests or use a jQuery script like the one below. This little script has been my preferred method as of late.

```
var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
if(path){
    $('#menu a[href="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'current');
    $('#subnav a[href="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'current');
}
```